# Biztalk - ExecutesendpipeLine()

Tags: biztalk

Input file:

```
<ns0:Emp xmlns:ns0="http://Test_Excepn.input">
  <ns1:EmpRecord xmlns:ns1="http://Test_Excepn.SingleSchema">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>N1</Name>
  </ns1:EmpRecord>
  <ns1:EmpRecord xmlns:ns1="http://Test_Excepn.SingleSchema">
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Name>N2</Name>
</ns1:EmpRecord>
  <ns1:EmpRecord xmlns:ns1="http://Test_Excepn.SingleSchema">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>N3</Name>
  </ns1:EmpRecord>
</ns0:Emp>
```

Expected Result:
  Apply business logic and filter out some record from Input file

Orchestration logic

1. Created envelop schema
2. Single schema
3. Loop the input file schema based on record count
4. Apply business logic
5. Add the single emp record in send pipeline
6. Exit the loop
7. EXECUTESENDPIPELINE

Craeted Sendpipeline with xmlassembler (Document schema as Singlemsg and envelopschema as Input_Envelop)
Created variable sendinputmessages type.

```
var_PipelineInputMessage_EMP.Add(Singlemsg);
```

Outside the loop

```
Input_Envelop = null;
Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteSendPipeline(typeof(SendPipeline_EMP), var_PipelineInputMessage_EMP, Input_Envelop);
```

But the when i am dumping Input_envelop no record is found in envelop schema.

Comment: Please post your exact error message. Then tell at what exact point it fails in your orchestration, you can see this by using the orchestration debugger. You're creating an envelope schema and then a single schema, before looping, why?

Comment: No error in Orachestration. But messages are not adding in pipeline.

Comment: Test the pipeline without the orchestration and see if it works.